# How to detect which memory is being used when answering a yes or no question?

Tags: memory, long-term-memory, semantic-memory, procedural-memory, episodic-memory

I am asking participants some questions on a form. I have to know which kind of memory they are using when answering these questions. I am having difficulty deciding this. Is there any special technique to determine this?

For example, consider these questions :

1. *Is your name Majid?* 
   Is the memory used semantic or episodic? I know that most probably everyone would say semantic because there is no event being recalled, but I am not sure if remembering own's name is possible without recalling an event.
2. *Is your hair black?*
   This one is only available while thinking of a memory, but like the last one it could be semantic too.
3. *Do you know how to ride a bike?*
   This one could be semantic or episodic because I might recall an event of riding a bike and then answer.  Or it could even be procedural memory as I might simulate riding a bike and then say, "Yes".

I am trying to figure out how do I assign each question one or more of the memory types?

I am using the memory types introduced by Squire in 2004.
The picture is from *Fundamentals of Cognitive Neuroscience* by Bernard Baars.
[image: Fundamentals of Cognitive Neuroscience by Bernard Baars]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is remembering a list of words an example of semantic or episodic memory?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/is-remembering-a-list-of-words-an-example-of-semantic-or-episodic-memory)

Comment: No this is not like, at least i couldn't find the similarity, I think there is a paper also about that thread

Answer (score 2):

**It depends** whether the answers are well known facts. If I know well my name, the color of my hair and whether I can ride a bike then semantic memory is used to answer these questions. If I have a doubt whether I can ride a bike, then I may use other types of memory like episodic or even procedural to come up with an answer.

Also, I may use episodic memory to answer a specific question today, but if I have to answer the same question tomorrow I will probably use semantic memory because it has become a general fact that is stored in semantic memory.

> [Semantic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_memory) reflects our knowledge of the world around us, hence
>   the term 'general knowledge' is often used. It holds generic
>   information that is more than likely acquired across various contexts
>   and is used across different situations.

Comment: so in your experiment how do you know if the participant is using semantic or episodic memory while answering the question about his/her name ?!